# Gulpfile builds successfully but output directory empty?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am building a Django/Python app and my Gulpfile runs with no problem.  It finishes all the tasks. However, the output directory is missing `dist.min.js` and `templates.js` which is really weird because this was not happening before: the files got converted there.

I did not edit any code so now I am puzzled at why Gulpfile runs successfully but does not output the files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `Gulpfile` to it. (If you select a block of code and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button it will be indented by four spaces and treated as code by SO.)

Comment: Have you checked user permissions in output directory?